# Force main thread to use Return on RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs

Tags: c#, multithreading, backgroundworker

In my application i set/get data in devices through infrared reader.
When i run my application i have two case :
- The device is here the whole time, i return an object 'RETOUR'
- The device was here at the beginning, but someone disconnect it when my function was running.

I would like to return an object of type 'RETOUR' in both case.

The entrance point is necessarily a function like this :
"public async Task XXX(dynamic input)"

I build a backgroundworker who find when the device is disconnected.
It work find but i don't know how to force my async task to return an object when the RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler is call.

Code of Backgroundworker launch in every "async Task" function :

```
        bw = new BackgroundWorker();
        bw.WorkerSupportsCancellation = true;

        bw.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(
        delegate (object o, DoWorkEventArgs args)
        {
            // called when AwaitEpdRemoval have response
            stack.EpdRemoved += (object sender, ConnectEventArgs e) =>
            {
                // Set the object i want to return
                STATIC_FUNCTION.mon_retour.GestionErreur("154", null);
            };

            // While AwaitEpdRemoval don't throw EpdRemoved object
            while (true && STATIC_FUNCTION.mon_retour.code_retour != "154")
            {
                try
                {
                    if (bw.CancellationPending) {
                        args.Cancel = true;
                        break;
                    }
                    // If device still here
                    stack.AwaitEpdRemoval(discoveredEpd);
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    // If the device is still the here the DLL throw error
                    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100);
                }
            }
        });

        // when the worker is completed
        bw.RunWorkerCompleted += new RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(
            delegate (object o, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs args)
            {
                // for now i close the app, but what i want is return STATIC_FUNCTION.mon_retour
                System.Environment.Exit(1);
            });

        bw.RunWorkerAsync();
```

For now it close everything, but i want it to stop other code and return object "STATIC_FUNCTION.mon_retour"

How can i do that (even if i have to re-write everthing).